# Is this hadith about prophet Musa sahih?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, prophet-musa

is this hadith authentic:

> Once Moosa (AS) asked Allah Ta'ala: O Allah! You have granted me the honor and privilege of talking to you directly, Have you given this privilege to any other person? Allah Ta'ala replied, O!! Moosa during the last period I am going to send an ummah, who will be the ummah of Mohammed (SAW) with dry lips, parched tongues, emaciated body with eyes sunken deep into their socks, with livers dry and stomachs suffering the pangs of hunger- will call out to me (in dua) they will be much closer to me than you O Moosa! while you speak to me there are 70000 veils between you and me but at the time of iftaar there will not be a single veil between me and the fasting Ummati of Mohammed (SAW) O!! Moosa I have taken upon myself the responsibility that at the time of iftaar I will never refuse the dua of a fasting person

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: @UmH why the bounty when your link provides an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum brother,

As per scholars of islam, This hadeeth mentioned is not in any of the reliable books, so it is not permissible to attribute it to the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) or to believe what it says.

Source: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/124410/veil-between-allah-and-his-slaves-lifted-at-time-of-breaking-fast

Answer (score 1):

According to [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/124410/veil-between-allah-and-his-slaves-lifted-at-time-of-breaking-fast), the narration is not found in any known book of ahadith. It is quoted in [Nuzhat al-Majalis wa Muntakhab al-Nafa’is](https://al-maktaba.org/book/28168/165#p1) without a chain of transmission, so its authenticity is unverifiable.

Objection may also be raised to its content, that a common fasting person from this Ummah has superiority over Moses  (عليه السلام). Such a thing is contrary to our creed that the Prophets have superiority over all creation.

> And We gave to Abraham, Isaac and Jacob - all [of them] We guided. And Noah, We guided before; and among his descendants, David and Solomon and Job and Joseph and **Moses** and Aaron. Thus do We reward the doers of good. And Zechariah and John and Jesus and Elias - and all were of the righteous. And Ishmael and Elisha and Jonah and Lot - and all [of them] **We preferred over the worlds.**
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:84-86](https://legacy.quran.com/6/84-86)</sup>

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, I don't see anything wrong with the mention of non Prophets being higher than Prophets. There is another ayat in the Quran that states: And We did certainly give the Children of Israel the Scripture and judgement and prophethood, and We provided them with good things and preferred them over the worlds. (Surah 45 verse 16). So does that mean the israelites are better than the ummah of the Prophet Muhammad (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him)? Even though in the Quran it is mentioned that we are the best nation to be raised (reference to Surah 3 verse 110).